# The correspondence between affine vector bundles and f.g. projective modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, ac.commutative-algebra

The definition of a (geometric) vector bundle over a scheme $X$ can be rewritten as follows in terms of 'not-so-geometrical algebra' if $X=Spec R$ is affine and if I am not missing something.

A *vector bundle* of rank $n$ over $R$ is an $R$-algebra $A$ such that

- for every $p\in Spec R$ there is a isomorphism (belonging to the data)
  $$
  \phi_p:k(p)[X_1,...,X_n]\xrightarrow{\cong} A\otimes_R k(p)
  $$
  where $k(p)$ is the residue field $R_p/m_p$ and
- there are elements $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ of $R$ such that the $D(a_i)=\{ I\in Spec R\mid a\notin I \}$ cover $Spec R$ and for every $i\in I$ there is an $R_a$-algebra isomorphism
  $$
  A\otimes_R R_{a_i}\xrightarrow{\cong}R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\otimes_RR_{a_i}
  $$
  which induces for every $p\in Spec R$ with $a_i\notin p$ a $k(p)$-**linear** $k(p)$-algebra isomorphism
  $$
  A\otimes_R k(p)~\xleftarrow{\phi_p}k(p)[X_1,...,X_n]\to k(p)[X_1,...,X_n]\cong R[X_1,...,X_n]\otimes_R k(p).
  $$

The (isomorphism classes) of such vector bundles over $R$ should correspond to (isomorphism classes) of finitely gererated projective modules over the ring $R$.

How can this correspondence be seen?

Comment: Isn't this just a special case of the correspondence between vector bundles and locally free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?  In which case, take your vector bundle and look at its sheaf of global sections (which will just be an $R$-module in your affine setting).

Comment: Yes, it is a special case. Unfortunately I do not understand the general case and what happens there with the symmetric algebra. This is why I would like to see how this works in the affine case.

Comment: It is a standard commutative algebra fact that a module is locally free of finite rank if and only if it is finitely generated and projective. You can find it in every good textbook (and of course, in Bourbaki).

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But why does the above correspond to a locally free module of finite rank?

Comment: This is also discussed in EGA 2 in the section on the relative proj construction.

Comment: I am missing the grading on $A$ in the above. One needs a grading to capture the multiplication with scalars. Recall that a grading amounts to having $\mathbb G_m$ act.  

Comment: Why should $A$ be graded? (vgl. Hartshorne Ex.5.18.) Do you perhaps mix this up with projective bundles?

Comment: No, I am not taking Proj. You want scalar multiplication on your bundle or what?

Comment: Sorry but I did not get your point. The above definition is the affine translation of the scheme theoretic one of Hartshorne. Where is the grading hidden in Hartshorne's definition?

Comment: It is hidden in the italicized word `linear'. For polynomial rings an automorphism of algebras respects the grading exactly when it is given by a linear map in the degree one part. When thinking about a projective module $P$ over a base ring $R$, the algebra of functions is the symmetric algebra over $R$ on the dual module, but as a graded algebra, so as not to forget the $R$-module structure on $P$. Your gluing maps should respect the module structure on $P$.
For instance, try how you would describe a translation by one on the affine line over a field. You get a map that is not graded.


Comment: Thank you very much for the correction! I am trying to understand what you mean and I need a little more time to do that. Maybe, you could help me with this: Have I only to assume that $A$ is graded or should any of the maps in the definition also be a graded?

Comment: Yes, the isomorphisms should all be graded. Notice also that the answer to your problem involves taking the degree one part of
each algebra and then using the patching data to patch these degree one parts as modules.
That way you get a projective module, possibly dual to the one you
were after.

Comment: Oh, I beg your pardon! I forgot the "linear" in the definition above and made an edit. Now, everything should be ok, right?

Comment: @roger123: Same problem remains:As Willberd van der Kallen says, you need a grading on A and isomorphisms must respect it.

Comment: I still do not understand. Since the isomorphism of the fiber $A_{k(p)}$ to the polynomial ring $k(p)[X_1,...,X_n]$ belongs to the data, $A_{k(p)}$ gets the grading from this isomorphism. Then everything should follow from the linearity of the restriction isomorphism, right?

Comment: First of all, if you use `linear' in the sense `compatible with grading', please say so. (E.g.: is the map $k[x]\to k[x]:p(x)\mapsto p(x+1)$ linear in your sense?) Secondly, why would you want $\phi_p$ to be part of the data? Are you trying to define the notion of `vector bundle with fixed basis in every fiber'? Thirdly, you do not impose any compatibility between isomorphisms on different sets $D(a_i)$, only between these isomorphisms and isomorphisms on fibers. This is going to be trouble if A has nilpotents.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, t3suji. With 'linear' I mean that every $a\in k$ is mapped to $a$ and $X_i$ is mapped to $\sum a_{i,j} X_j$. I want $\phi_p$ to be part of the data, like in the topological definition. The third point is very helpful, thank you! It is 'solved' if I replace each $k(p)$ by $R_p$, and demand the automorphism on $R_p[X_1,...,X_n]$ induced by the restriction to be linear, right? Again, thank you for the very helpful comments.

Comment: Thank you, makes better sense now. The usage of `linear' is very confusing, by the way. For the second point: but $\phi_p$ is not part of the data in topological picture! One should require a structure of a vector space on the fiber, but you don't fix an isomorphism with the standard vector space. If you want to imitate this, you should require an isomorphism with the symmetric algebra of a vector space, not with the polynomial algebra (which is the symmetric algebra of the standard vector space). For the third point: yes, this would solve it.

Comment: Ok, then I do understand, finally and we have produced the most comments to a question :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given any $R$-module $M$, there is a scheme which corresponds to the 'total space' of $M$, given by 
$$ Tot(M):=Spec( Sym_R(M*))$$
where $M*$ is the dual module $Hom_R(M,R)$ and $Sym_RM*$ is the symmetric algebra of $M^*$ over $R$.  If $M$ happens to a free rank $n$ $R$-module, then $Sym_RM\simeq R[X_1,...,X_n]$.  The scheme $Tot(M)$ has a natural map to $Spec(R)$, which is dual to the obvious inclusion
$$R\rightarrow Sym_RM$$

If you start with a locally free, finite rank $R$-module $P$, and then consider its total space $Tot(P)$, the corresponding scheme is a vector bundle by your definition.  This follows from considering open sets on which $P$ is free, and considering the restriction of $Tot(P)$ over those open sets.  Since restriction to an open set is the same as tensoring over the localization, and localization commutes with forming symmetric algebras, the locally freeness becomes your second condition.  The first condition is also straightforward.

Then, observe that *every* vector bundle by your definition arises this way.  To see this, follow Mike's comment.  Associate to a vector bundle $V$ its sheaf of sections over $Spec(R)$, which is an $R$-module in a natural way.  It will be free over the open cover $D(a_i)$, with constant rank $n$.

Edit: As pointed out by roger, the total space construction should use the dual of $M$.  As a side note, this means that it is the same if you replace $M$ with $M^{**}$, and so it is not interesting to apply this construction to non-reflexive modules.

Comment: Thank you, Greg. Don't I have to consider $Sym_R M^*$, the symmetric algebra of the dual of $M$?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is correct.  Sorry, I changed it at the last minute from the free case.

Answer (score 1):

It may make more sense to look at the isomorphism class of a vector bundle as its corresponding isomorphism class as a locally free sheaf (Hartshorne: Algebraic Geometry - Exercise 5.18)

Then, it becomes clearer to see the connection by looking at the sheaf associated to a projective module $M$ - which is a locally free sheaf, since the the stalk at any $p \in SpecR$ is isomorphic to $M_p \simeq R^n$, and we have an open cover of $X=SpecR$ by the $D(a_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there are many excellent answers above and included in the comments, let me try to offer an alternative view.

Let's say that $E\to X$ is a trivial geometric vector bundle. As a scheme, $E\simeq X\times \mathbb A^r$ (and I am simplifying a little bit, but the point here is intuition I suppose). Anyway, now if $X={\rm Spec}R$, then what is $E$? Well, what else but ${\rm Spec} R[x_1,\dots,x_r]$? And what is $E_x$ for some $x\in X$? If $x$ corresponds to the prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$ then $E_x$ is just $\kappa(\mathfrak p)[x_1,\dots,x_r]$.

OK, now if $E\to X$ is not trivial, but *locally* trivial, then the only thing that changes is that these should hold over some open cover of $X$. The topology of $X$ has a base by open sets of the form $D(a)$, so we may as well take our open cover consists of such open sets.

In other words we recovered your two conditions. Now go and check (possibly at the suggested references) that you can do the construction backwards.